# Convert a Pandas DataFrame with repetitive keys to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns. I want to convert this DataFrame to a python dictionary. I want the elements of first column be `keys` and the elements of other columns in same row be `values`. However, entries in the first column are repeated -

```
Keys    Values
1       1
1       6
1       9
2       3
3       1
3       4
```

The `dict` I want is  - `{1: [1,6,9], 2: [3], 3: [1,4]}`

I am using the code - `mydict=df.set_index('Keys').T.to_dict('list')` however, the output has only unique values of keys. `{1: [9], 2: [3], 3: [4]}`

Comment: How about using groupBy ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the `'Keys'` column and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) `list` and call [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html#pandas.Series.to_dict):

```
In[32]:
df.groupby('Keys')['Values'].apply(list).to_dict()

Out[32]: {1: [1, 6, 9], 2: [3], 3: [1, 4]}
```

Breaking down the above into steps:

```
In[35]:
# groupby on the 'Keys' and apply list to group values into a list
df.groupby('Keys')['Values'].apply(list)
Out[35]: 
Keys
1    [1, 6, 9]
2          [3]
3       [1, 4]
Name: Values, dtype: object
```

convert to a dict

```
In[37]:
# make a dict
df.groupby('Keys')['Values'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[37]: {1: [1, 6, 9], 2: [3], 3: [1, 4]}
```

Thanks to @P.Tillman for the suggestion that `to_frame` was unnecessary, kudos to him

Comment: Why do you use to_frame instead of directly to_dict on the series you get from apply?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df.groupby('Keys')['Values'].unique().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: array([1, 6, 9]), 2: array([3]), 3: array([1, 4])}
```